# How to load data when opening an application?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api

I have written the code correctly, but for some reason, after calling the method for `fetchData()`, `superHero` array remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
class MainViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    private var superHeroes = [SuperHero]()

    let url = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/akabab/superhero-api/0.2.0/api/all.json"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchData()
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return superHeroes.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        let superHeroe = superHeroes[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(superHero: superHeroe)


        return cell
    }

    func fetchData() {

        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                self.superHeroes = try JSONDecoder().decode([SuperHero].self, from: data)
                print(self.superHeroes)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should called collectionView.reloadData() after decoding the response

Comment: Thanks! Now is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't posted your `SuperHero` `Codable` I have created new one accourding to your `JSON` from [HERE](https://app.quicktype.io). And it looks like:

```
typealias SuperHero = [SuperHeroElement]

struct SuperHeroElement: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, slug: String
    let powerstats: Powerstats
    let appearance: Appearance
    let biography: Biography
    let work: Work
    let connections: Connections
    let images: Images
}

struct Appearance: Codable {
    let gender: Gender
    let race: String?
    let height, weight: [String]
    let eyeColor, hairColor: String
}

enum Gender: String, Codable {
    case empty = "-"
    case female = "Female"
    case male = "Male"
}

struct Biography: Codable {
    let fullName, alterEgos: String
    let aliases: [String]
    let placeOfBirth, firstAppearance: String
    let publisher: String?
    let alignment: Alignment
}

enum Alignment: String, Codable {
    case bad = "bad"
    case empty = "-"
    case good = "good"
    case neutral = "neutral"
}

struct Connections: Codable {
    let groupAffiliation, relatives: String
}

struct Images: Codable {
    let xs, sm, md, lg: String
}

struct Powerstats: Codable {
    let intelligence, strength, speed, durability: Int
    let power, combat: Int
}

struct Work: Codable {
    let occupation, base: String
}
```

Now next thing is you need to replace:

```
private var superHeroes = [SuperHero]()
```

with

```
private var superHeroes: SuperHero?
```

And in your `fetchData` method replace

```
self.superHeroes = try JSONDecoder().decode([SuperHero].self, from: data)
```

with

```
self.superHeroes = try JSONDecoder().decode(SuperHero.self, from: data)
```

here `superHeroes` is an `Array` of `SuperHeroElement` so you can access data through index from it. like

```
guard let response = self.superHeroes else {return}
print(response[0].images) //Accessing data at 0 index
```

Also you need to reload your collection view once you got the data from server in main queue like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

you can put `self.collectionView.reloadData()` in `do` condition after you print `superHero` array in `fetchData()` method.